# Value not being fetched from data-x tags

Tags: jquery, json, html, loops, attributes

I am trying to fetch values from two data attributes contained within  elements.
If I use:

```
data = $('tr th', a).data() ;
```

Then try to fetch using:

```
data[0] // This works.
data[1] // Comes out as undefined.
```

Here is the part of my script that is doing this, which currently works because I'm using .attr() to get the values:

```
$('tr th', a).each(function(){
        sql = $(this).attr('data-sql') ;
        dir = $(this).attr('data-direction') ;

        if(sql)
        {
            JSONCols += '"'+sql+'", ' ;
        }
        if(!dir)
        {
            dir = '' ;
        }
        JSONDirs += '"'+dir+'", ' ;
    })
```

How can I use just .data() to fetch the two values instead of using .attr() so my code is cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

Treat it like an object, `data.sql`, `data.direction`

Note however this only gets the data from the first selected element. If you want data from them all, you'll have to use an iterating function such as a `for loop`, `while loop`, `$.each`, `$().each`, `$.map`, or `$().map`.

```
var data = $('tr th', a).map(function(){
    return $(this).data();
}).get();
console.log(data[0].sql);
```